# Upload apk to existing play store project after adding flavors

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I want to upload a new version of my app, but I can't because I added flavors so the package name has changed from:

> com.myapp.android

to

> com.myapp.android.flavor1

Inside my build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
    main {
        applicationId 'com.myapp.android'
        versionName '1.0'
        versionCode 4
    }
    flavor1 {
        applicationId 'com.myapp.android.flavor1 '
        versionName '1.0'
        versionCode 5
    }
   }
```

If I change the applicationId of flavor1 to 'com.myapp.android' I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processMainDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> > No matching client found for package name 'com.myapp.android'

So my question is, should I try to fix that error (and if yes how?) or is there any other work around ?

Comment: What happens if you just leave "applicationId" out of the flavor section?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but reading [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) it seemd that just taking "applicationId" out of both flavor sections (main and flavor1) should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The new applicationId should be in your google-services.json as well.